# Missions at or soon-to-be at Mars and their DSN "codenames"?

Tags: mars, spacecraft, deep-space-network

I'm "mining" old DSN data and would like to see all communications with spacecraft around Mars. A quick snapshot in their data shows the following codes. I can guess that `MRO` is Mars Reconasence Orbiter and `MSL` is Mars Science Laboratory, but I'm only 99% sure of these, and not sure how many others.

On this page https://deepspace.jpl.nasa.gov/ I see MISSIONS and Current, but if I click it I actually get the "Great Galactic Ghoul!" (click for full size - If you dare!)

[image: Great Galactic Ghoul]

I think there are about six spacecraft there, but not sure what codes to use to search the DSN data, any suggestions?

A random, small "snapshot" sample, will try to get a longer one soon...

```
'RSTS', 'CHDR', 'CASS', 'MSGR', 'MVN', 'M01O', 'MRO', 'DAWN', 'CAS', 'STA', 
'MER1', 'RSTS', 'VGR1', 'MSL', 'ACE', 'KEPL','THC', 'GBRA'
```

Is this what's active at Mars now, or in the last few years at least?

- ExoMars? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExoMars_Trace_Gas_Orbiter
- MVN?     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAVEN
- MOM?     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Orbiter_Mission
- MRO?     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Reconnaissance_Orbiter
- MEX?     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Express
- MO?      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001_Mars_Odyssey

Comment: in DSN Now you can click on the abbreviation and get some info on the spacecraft in the sidebar. That should solve the problem for active missions. The /missions page should have a list of past missions. I checked the Internet Archive, but that doesn't have that page archived.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a list of the current missions that use the DSN (including their acronyms) at https://www.cdscc.nasa.gov/Pages/trackingtoday.html

As @Hobbes said in another answer, of the past missions CAS / CASS are probably Cassini, and MSRG would be Mercury Messenger. RSTS could be Rosetta. GBRA is apparently "either Network activities in radio astronomy, maintenance or systems development".

There's a good list of all the missions to Mars at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missions_to_Mars which includes current status.

Comment: Thank you for your help and quick turnaround! Can you take a look to see how [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25921/12102) looks?

Comment: @uhoh yes, it looks right to me.

Comment: This is the answer that solved my problem, thanks! The CDSCC page was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 6):

In DSN Now you can click on the abbreviation and get some info on the spacecraft in the sidebar

From [NASA's mission list](https://www.nasa.gov/missions/current/index.html):

ACE: [Advanced Composition Explorer](http://www.srl.caltech.edu/ACE/)
CHDR: [Chandra](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/chandra/main/index.html) X-ray observatory
CASS: [Cassini](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/cassini/main/index.html)
(CAS could be Cassini as well, found no other missions it could fit)
DAWN: [Dawn](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/dawn/main/index.html)
GO17: GOES 17
KEPL: [Kepler](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/kepler/main/index.html)
MER: [Mars Exploration Rovers Spirit and Opportunity](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/mer/index.html) (dunno which is which)
MSL: [Mars Science Laboratory](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/msl/index.html)
M01O: Mars Odyssey
MVN: [MAVEN](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/maven/main/index.html)
MSGR: [Messenger](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/messenger/main/index.html)
STA: STEREO A
THC: THEMIS C
VGR1/2: [Voyager](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/voyager/index.html)

that leaves RSTS.

Comment: According to the link in my answer, STA is STEREO A.

Comment: Thank you for your help and quick turnaround! Can you take a look to see how [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25921/12102) looks?

Answer (score 2):

The OP says:

> I'm "mining" old DSN data and would like to see all communications with spacecraft around *Mars*.

and asks if the list of six missions is

> ...what's active at *Mars* now, or in the last few years at least?

Based on help from both @Hobes' [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25916/12102) and @djr's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25917/12102) and especially the [Canberra DSN page](https://www.cdscc.nasa.gov/Pages/trackingtoday.html) linked there, it looks like the items in a DSN data stream within the last few years that may be from Mars are the following:

```
M01O    Mars Odyssey                    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001_Mars_Odyssey
MER 1   Mars Rover: Opportunity(1)      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_(rover)
MEX     Mars Express (ESA)              https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Express
MOM     Mars Orbiter Mission (India)    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Orbiter_Mission
MRO     Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Reconnaissance_Orbiter
MSL     Mars Science Laboratory         https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Science_Laboratory
          Curiosity Mars Rover          https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiosity_(rover)
MVN     MAVEN: Mars atmosphere mission  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAVEN
TGO     Exo Mars Trace Gas Orbiter      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExoMars_Trace_Gas_Orbiter
```

Answer (score 2):

For the three newest additions to the objects at mars, the following codes are used by DSN:

```
NSYT   Insight
MCOA   MarCO A
MCOB   MarCO B
```