# Is it common for the Deep Space Network to contact a TDRS satellite?

Tags: deep-space-network, tdrss

As I write this, one of the Madrid dishes of the [Deep Space Network](https://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html) is in contact with [TDRS satellite #13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TDRS-13).

I've never seen DSN contact a TDRS satellite before.  I thought that system has its own dishes.  **Has DSN been used to contact a TDRS satellite before?**  Why is it contacting TDRS-13 now?  Isn't Madrid 180 degrees from where the satellite is supposed to be?  Does this have something to do with [that satellite's past problems](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23225/26446)?

[image: Madrid to TDRS-13]

Comment: Fascinating question! [n2yo](https://www.n2yo.com/?s=42915&live=1) currently [shows it easily viewable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9wO7.jpg) from [DSN Madrid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madrid_Deep_Space_Communications_Complex) so I've therefore unaccepted my "Yes" answer to [Is TDRS-M (TDRS-13) where it's supposed to be?](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26255/12102) when it was near 150° W.

Comment: [This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25917/12102) to *Missions at or soon-to-be at Mars and their DSN “codenames”?* links to https://www.cdscc.nasa.gov/Pages/trackingtoday.html with abbreviations for *deep space* missions tracked by Canberra. Interestingly, the https://www.mdscc.nasa.gov/ site does not have a corresponding page, at least by simple replacement of cdscc with mdscc, so is there some way that we can be 100% certain that TD13 is TDRSS-13?

Comment: [as you know](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32480/12102) DSN historical activity can be downloaded and searched for previous contacts with TDRS as discussed in [Understanding the information contained in the Deep Space Network XML data?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32479/12102) and in [Is there any publicly available logging, or “Wayback Machine” for DSN Now activity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17046/12102) I don't have the personal bandwidth to do so these days but presumably something like this could be done to see how often this happens.

Comment: I didn't screencapture the whole DSN Now page, but the spacecraft details clearly specified that TD13 is TDRS-13.